# JavaScript Regex for Path without leading or trailing slashes

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, filepath

I'm struggling to figure out a Regex pattern for JavaScript that will trim a path of it's preceding and trailing slashes (or hashes/extensions)

For example:

```
path/
/path
/folder/path/
/folder/folder/path
/folder/path#hash
/folder/path.ext
```

Should return:

```
path
path
folder/path
folder/folder/path
folder/path
folder/path
```

I felt like I was getting close with the following, but it only selects text without any slashes, hashes, or periods.

```
^([^\\\/\#\.]*)(?![\#\.\\\/].*$)/gm
```

I'm trying to use this for Regex in a vuetify text-field validation, if that's at all helpful.

## ***Result***

I ended up with this regex slug

```
/^(?![\#\/\.\$\^\=\*\;\:\&\?\(\)\[\]\{\}\"\'\>\<\,\@\!\%\`\~\s])(?!.*[\#\/\.\$\^\=\*\;\:\&\?\(\)\[\]\{\}\"\'\>\<\,\@\!\%\`\~\s]$)[^\#\.\$\^\=\*\;\:\&\?\(\)\[\]\{\}\"\'\>\<\,\@\!\%\`\~\s]*$/
```

https://regexr.com/66ol9

Comment: Validation doesn't change the contents, it just tells you if it matches the regexp or not.

Comment: Correct. I just want to reject if they have a preceding or trailing slash, or hash tag, etc.

Comment: I also tried (?![\\\/\#\.])[\w\-\\\/\_]+(?![\\\/\#\.$]+)/gm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it is achieved with no lookbehinds (they are still rejected in Safari :():

```js
^(?![#\/.])(?!.*[#\/.]$).*
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/r9nMc7/1). And...

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [#\/.]                   any character of: '#', '\/', '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [#\/.]                   any character of: '#', '\/', '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Comment: Thank you for this breakdown. I'm still capturing `folder/path#hash` but would like to avoid this possible case as well. I'm confused why this wouldn't be captured by the first lookahead? https://regex101.com/r/dYjqWQ/1

Comment: @broxen To avoid strings with hash symbol, use negated character class, `^(?![#\/.])(?!.*[#\/.]$)[^#]*$`. See https://regex101.com/r/dYjqWQ/2

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookahead at the beginning, and negative lookbehind at the end.

```
/^(?![#\/.]).*(?<![#\/.])$/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/M0NvsX/1)

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Unfortunately, I'm not getting the desired results. I tried your demo and https://regexr.com/66nk9

Comment: It seems to be working at your regexr. All the paths beginning with `/` were rejected.